# Simulating the English "ch" with German text to speech engine

Tags: pronunciation, software

I am having the Mac German speech synthesizer Markus speak lyrics to a song.  I find his accent charming.  The lyrics are in English.

For this endeavor, one types text and then passes them to the speech engine which then speaks them.

I am struggling to figure out how to get Markus to make the English sound "ch" as in "chubby".  It is obviously not just "ch" which comes out as a sort of k.  It comes out Qbee.  I have tried the ü but that does not come out as the soft u either.

How would you write "chubby" in German?  How can I get Markus to make it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about German language. It is about configuring some software.

Comment: "Tschabbi" should come close.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - it is a question about a sound that occurs in English, and whether that sound occurs in German.  The software piece was added for context so the motivation behind the question is understood.  I found a fair bit written about the converse - the sound "ch" represents in German apparently does not occur in English.

Comment: The close reason is wrong. The question is how close you can come to the pronunciation of *chubby* using only German sounds and how such a German word would be spelled.

Comment: Does the software support IPA? Because then, you could simply cut+paste the IPA representation from English wiktionary and see how the German voice would pronounce it.

Comment: @CarstenS: Well, if you are right, the question should be closed for being *unclear what you're asking*. So it should be closed anyway.

Comment: @Hubert "How would you write 'chubby' in German" is a clear enough question.

Comment: If tschabbi doesn't work, try tsjabbi or tsjöbbi.

Comment: @Hubert: if Willk had asked the question saying "I have to explain a German friend, who doesn't speak English **at all**, how to pronounce *chubby*. How would I write that in German, so he can pronounce it properly? Oh, and he doesn't know phonemes/IPA/any such thing", it would not be unclear and it would not be off-topic, IMO. That this "friend" is in reality a piece of software doesn't change the question.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: You wrote: »if Willk had asked [...] it would not be unclear and it would not be off-topic.« Yes, you are right. But he didn't ask your version. The original question still is either unclear or a question about software, and needs to closed in both cases. The OP still has the chance to edit his question and to make it on-topic.

Comment: @Hubert: I don't think it makes a difference if he asked it for a friend or for himself (so he could configure the software properly). Same basic question. The software thing was just background and irrelevant to us. And the question is IMO crystal clear.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: You are just repeating your old argument.

Comment: @Hubert: indeed. Obviously you didn't get it ithe first time: your arguments for closure don't hold.

Comment: @tofro Warum schreibst Du Deinen Vorschlag "tschabbi", den ich auch für richtig halte, nicht als Antwort?

Comment: @tofro Da muss ich Volker zustimmen. Mach ne Antwort draus, dann ist das Thema durch.

Answer (score 2):

"Tschabbi" should come close. I have asked Markus to say that and it sounded acceptable to my ears.

Comment: I don’t understand the low quality flag. This is exactly the answer to the question. I can’t think of any better way to spell a word that fits the sound of the English *chubby* (i.e. that emulates the sound *chubby* when read according to German spelling pronunciation).

Comment: @Philipp would actually expect longer, more detailed answers in SE myself - So I can partially understand the flag. In this specific answer, however, there isn't much more to say without starting to babble....